# Create an Acknolwedge Window on Visit

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I'm new to React and have been watching tutorials on passing props. I am trying to create a simple acknowledge window when a visitor comes to my website. The window loads automatically on visit and the user clicks acknowledge and moves on. Problem is, is that I can't get the function to pass to close the window and use the localStorage so the window doesn't keep popping up when the user moves through out the site. Any advice to what I am doing wrong?

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Dialog from './Components/dialog';

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <Dialog>
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet drumstick pancetta swine ball tip chicken, sausage shank spare ribs turducken. Picanha pig doner short loin alcatra. Shankle prosciutto beef pork loin, leberkas salami tri-tip capicola. Picanha porchetta alcatra spare ribs turducken shankle ribeye swine biltong meatloaf pastrami. Ribeye landjaeger filet mignon pork chop capicola boudin shoulder pork belly doner andouille buffalo kielbasa pancetta bresaola. Cow jerky biltong prosciutto drumstick turducken shank pastrami frankfurter venison pig. Pork chop doner kevin porchetta burgdoggen shankle chislic tenderloin shoulder.
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

### dialog.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

let dialogStyles = {
     width: '700px',
     height: '300px',
     maxWidth: '100%',
     margin: '0 auto',
     position: 'fixed',
    left: '50%',
    top: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%,-50%)',
    zIndex: '999',
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    padding: '10px 20px 40px',
    borderRadius: '8px',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column'
   };

   let boxStyle ={
       display: 'none'
   }

   let dialogCloseButtonStyles = {
     marginBottom: '15px',
     padding: '3px 8px',
     cursor: 'pointer',
     borderRadius: '50%',
     border: 'none',
     width: '30px',
     height: '30px',
     fontWeight: 'bold',
     alignSelf: 'flex-end'
  };

 let ackStyles = {
     fontWeight: 'bold',
     padding: '5px',
     width: '120px',
     height:' 50px',
     backgroundColor: '#a6a6a6',
     cursor: 'pointer',
     border: 'none',
     position: 'top-bottom',
     borderRadius: '5%',
     alignSelf: 'center'
   };

  let ackForm = {
     alignSelf: 'center'
  };

 class Dialog extends Component {
     state = {
       isOpen: true
 } 

componentDidMount(){
    const isOpen = sessionStorage.getItem('isOpen') === 'false' 
    this.setState({ isOpen });
}

handleChange = (e) => {
    const input = e.target;
    const value = input.type === 'checkbox' ? input.checked : input.value;
}

ackSubmit = () => {
    const { isOpen } = this.state;
    sessionStorage.setItem('isOpen', isOpen);
};

render() {
    return (
        <div style={dialogStyles}>
            <div>{this.props.children}</div>
            <br/>
            <form onSubmit={this.ackSubmit} style={ackForm}>
                <input style={boxStyle} name='isOpen' checked={this.state.isOpen} onChange={this.handleChange} type="checkbox" />
                <button style={ackStyles} onChange={(e) => this.setState({       isOpen: false })}>ACKNOWLEDGE</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
   }
 }

export default Dialog;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you're setting `isOpen: true` in the `state` of your `Dialog` class, and then only checking whether it should be open or not *after* the component already mounts.

I would try this next:

```
class Dialog extends Component {
    state = {
        isOpen: !localStorage["alreadyVisited"];
    }
...
```

Comment: thank you for the feed back, but in modifying the code to the above, am I removing the true and false statements to null and alreadyVisited? I did modify the code but the function still isn't passing, I appreciate the patience.

Comment: It depends on what values you’re saving in localStorage. If you save true or false to “alreadyVisited”, that’s the value that will get assigned to state.isOpen.

Comment: I've updated my dialog.js, thanks for the tip, I didn't use it but you sparked my mind to think in a new way. I went with using sessionStorage instead of localStorage. Kicker now is that I can't get my dialog to close now. I've been starring at this thing all day, and I'm stumped.